# How to update arraylist in another activity on deletion?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have Arraylist which populate in one activity but deletion of items of that arraylist is happening in another activity. So how should I update the original ArrayList?

In Activity 1 :

```
 FloatingActionButton show = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.showB);
    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", foo);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key2", foo2);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key3", foo3);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

In Activity 2 :

```
    final ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");
    final ArrayList<String> list2 = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key2");
    final ArrayList<String> list3 = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key3");
```

//Deletion in Activity 2 :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ?");
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    list.remove(positionToRemove);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }});
            adb.show();
        }

    });
```

Now it deletes successfully in activity 2 but it is not updated to original arraylist in activity one.

Comment: y creating 3 different arraylist instead of 1

Comment: I need 3 for different purposes, just showed deletion of one so you get  the idea.

Comment: Its not deleting cuz there is no arraylist in activity 1 its always static list which has fixed size and fixed value. that would be better if you create arraylist in activity 1 and then send it to activity 2

Comment: It is created, it's not fixed size. It's populated and then sent to activity 2

Comment: show complete code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing arraylists through Intent , create a global variable for arraylist in Singleton class and access the arraylist from it. This will help in easy modification/ updating of the arraylist from anywhere in the application.

```
public class MySingleton
{
  private static  MySingleton mSingleton;
  public static ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>;

  public static MySingleton getInstance()
  {
    if(mSingleton == null)
      mSingleton = new MySingleton();
    else
       return mSingleton;
  }
}
```

Use the arraylist declared in this singleton class any where in your application

In Your activity:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().myList; // add/update the list
```

Answer (score -1):

make it :

```
public static ArrayList<String> l1
```